# La Pagina no esta redigiriendo adecuadamente

Tags: php, login, session

Me explico aca me han ayudado a hacer un login controlado en pdo de momento todo marcha bien hasta cierto punto al agregar seguridad.php al index del modulo me indica el navegador que se esta redirigiendo mal no se porque si tiene la ruta correcta este es mi codigo

Login.php

```html
<?php



 $correo=$_POST['correo'];
 $clave=md5($_POST['clave']);
 require_once('Conexion.php');
 $conn = Conectar();

 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT  id_usuario, nombre, apellido, correo, p.id_perfil, perfil FROM usuario u INNER JOIN perfil p ON p.id_perfil=u.id_perfil WHERE u.correo=:correo AND u.clave=:clave");
 $stmt->bindParam(':correo',$correo);
 $stmt->bindParam(':clave',$clave);
 $stmt->execute();
 
 
 if($stmt->rowCount()>=1){
  session_start();
  $fila=$stmt->fetch();
  if($fila['id_perfil']==1)
   {header("Location: administrador/index.php");}
  if($fila['id_perfil']==2)
   {header("Location: aprendiz/index.php");}
  if($fila['id_perfil']==3)
   {header("Location: root/index.php");}
 }
 else{
   echo "<font color='red'>Datos No Validos</font>";
 }

 


?>
```

Seguridad.php

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['id_perfil'])==1){
  header("Location: index.php");
 }
```

al quitar seguridad.php de el index del modulo entra normal pero no es algo que quiero ya que si la quito cualquiera con saber su url puede entrar
como puedo solucionar esto y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si pudieras cargar una captura de pantalla del error o algo que explique mejor la pregunta sería bueno, De momento prueba agregando lo siguiente al inicio y al final del código:

```
   ob_start();
    //TU CODIGO FUENTE
   ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: 269, bienvenid@ a SOes. No me queda muy claro si esta es una respuesta definitiva a tu pregunta o solo estas pidiendo por mas explicaciones. Si es una respuesta definitiva, trata de explicar como ayuda tu respuesta al problema (como un valor agregado). Si no era tu intención publicar una respuesta, quizas puedas borrarla y estoy seguro que pronto podrás llegar a 50 de reputación y podras comentar en todas partes. Todo con animos de mantener la calidad del sitio para futuros visitantes. Saludos!

Comment: me refiero es que al poner mi codigo de seguridad la pagina no carga pero al quitarlo si carga y el problema de quitarlo es que cualquiera puede entrar con tan solo saber su url

Comment: Prueba solo con esto: if (!isset($_SESSION['id_perfil'])) { } //no realices la comparación

Comment: deja entrar normal sin haberse logeado primero y eso es lo que trato de evitar

Comment: no debería de ingresar porque ese trozo de código valida si la sesión existe, Presumo que el problemas es que realizas el isset y la comparación con el tipo de usuario en el mismo if, separarlo y ve lo que pasa.

Comment: me da un ejemplo no entendi :D